# CKEditor v4: How to remove width and height after uploadimage plugin (drag an drop)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

After image upload on ckeditor (drag and drop), the image has added width and height. How to remove it?
Example: config.image2_prefillDimensions = false;

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: [SOLVED] Removing width and height on onUploaded function inside ckeditor.js, worked!